# selecting top 5 client by ticket sales with multiple records

Tags: sql

```
select client#,
       SUM(ticketpurchase.totalamount) value
from ops$yyang00.ticketpurchase,
     ops$yyang00.performance,
     ops$yyang00.production
where ticketpurchase.per# = performance.per# and
      performance.P#=production.P# and
      season#=1
group by client#
order by value desc;
```

How to select top 5 client in this for each season by ticket sale value one value can include multiple client..

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. SQL Server, MySQL)?  Can you show us your expected output?

Comment: What RDBMS you use? please edit your question and add the tag (SQL Server , MySQL ...etc)

Comment: ANSI SQL: add `FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code for sql server.

```
Select * from (
    select client#,SUM(ticketpurchase.totalamount) value,
    row_number() over(order by SUM(ticketpurchase.totalamount)) rowNo
    from ops$yyang00.ticketpurchase,
         ops$yyang00.performance,
         ops$yyang00.production
    where ticketpurchase.per# = performance.per# and
          performance.P#=production.P# and
          season#=1
    group by client#
) as t
where rowNo <=5
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** (*If you are using SQL Server*)

```
select top 5 from (
                    select client#,
                           SUM(ticketpurchase.totalamount) value
                    from ops$yyang00.ticketpurchase,
                         ops$yyang00.performance,
                         ops$yyang00.production
                    where ticketpurchase.per# = performance.per# and
                          performance.P#=production.P# and
                          season#=1
                    group by client# )
order by value desc
```

**Note:** *If you want the least 5 records*, *remove the* `desc` *from* `order by`